# Pass an anonymous arrow function as an object value in TSX

Tags: reactjs, tsx

I'm using two external components, one of which is a `DatePicker` that supports

```
onChange    
((val?: string | undefined) => void) | undefined
```

ex.

```
 <DatePicker id="test" 
             onChange={(val) => {console.log('Changed, val = ' + val)}}
```

and the other is a `DatePickerRange` consisting of two `DatePicker`s where each one gets a property object as

```
    <DateRangePicker
        startDatePickerProps={{
            id: 'dateFrom',
            onChange: ...
        }}
        endDatePickerProps={{
            id: 'dateFrom',
            onChange: ...
        }}
```

First of all, I already have state variables with setters that I wish I could use directly instead of anonymous arrow functions, as in

```
 <DatePicker id="test" 
             onChange={setDateFrom}`
```

but that gives me the TSX error

```
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>' is not assignable to type '(val?: string | undefined) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'val' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<string>'.
```

Since I can't use my setters directly, I have to specify inline arrow functions. My main question is, when it comes to the property objects for the `DateRangePicker`, I can't use the below syntax. How do I specify inline arrow functions inside an object?

```
    <DateRangePicker
        startDatePickerProps={{
            id: 'dateFrom',
            onChange: {(val) => {console.log('Changed, val = ' + val)}} /* SYNTAX ERROR */
        }}
        endDatePickerProps={{
            id: 'dateTo',
            onChange: {(val) => {console.log('Changed, val = ' + val)}} /* SYNTAX ERROR */
        }}
```

Comment: You remove the start and end curly brace so it reads `onChange: () => {}`. Another option would be to use `onChange() {}` but you'd have to modify your code example slightly.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, that worked. Is there a performance penalty from these inline functions? Should I be using my state setters that already available? And how would I get around the error `Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>' is not assignable to type '(val?: string | undefined) => void'.` ?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about any performance penalty from using an inline function, it won't make a difference. If you wanted to use your function you'd have to match function signatures so the types are satisfied.